# Running Node.js project within the Puppeteer Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I'd like to use the official [Puppeteer Docker image](https://pptr.dev/guides/docker) to run my project in production. The core mission of the project is to create pdf files of web pages and serve them over http (express).

I develop in TypeScript, in VS Code. So, I'd prefer to follow the normal practices of maintaining a Node.js project: `package.json` file with dev and prod dependencies, `node_modules` directory where VS Code can find the TS types for compiling the ts code, etc.

However, the inital state of the official Puppeteer Docker image is kind of specific: the puppeteer is not installed globally, and the `/home/pptruser` directory is a repository set up with this `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@puppeteer/browsers": "file:puppeteer-browsers-latest.tgz",
    "puppeteer": "file:puppeteer-latest.tgz",
    "puppeteer-core": "file:puppeteer-core-latest.tgz"
  }
}
```

, and the `/home/pptruser/node_modules` directory has the packages installed.

So, I wonder, what would be the most appropriate way to maintain my project so that I can develop and run it locally on my dev machine, and also deploy it to the container. Obviously, when I run it locally, I don't have the same `package.json` as the one in the container. I could copy (upon the container init) the source code `/src` directory to container's `/home/pptruser/src` and run a shell script that installs all the dev and prod packages with number of `npm install <name>` commands, instead of the traditional `npm install`. That would be one way to handle the task, I guess, although it forces me to duplicate the package names (both in the shell script and `package.json`). Perhaps there's more natural way? I usually prefer to establish volume that makes the project source directory (on the host) accessible in the container's file system, but in this case this approach does not seem to be possible, as there is already a pre-setup node repository present.

Answer (score 0):

Create a derived image and install whatever packages are required by your application.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest

WORKDIR /home/pptruser/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

CMD node
```

`package.json` (For testing I'll install `lodash`, but you would replace this with whatever is required for your application.)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

Now build and run. You can validate that both packages are available:

- `puppeteer` from the base image and
- `lodash` installed in the derived image.

You can achieve the same thing via a volume mount but it makes more sense to install packages at build time than run time.

[image]

Comment: That's surprising! How does the final package.json look like for this project? I would have expected that creating the `/home/pptruser/app` directory, copying the `package.json` file there, and running `npm install` would just result in a separate project. In your example the packages of two projects have somehow magically merged together.

Comment: Give it a try using my code and verify for yourself. I'm happy to be proven wrong (in which can I will iterate my answer!). 